# Behavior of Tags

Tags: contacts, tags

In using tags and creating searches based on tags - I have run into some issues.

Tag Tree Example

```
Tag Set 1
     Parent A
          Child A1
             Child A1a
             Child A1b
                 Child A1ba
                 Child A1bb 
             Child A1c 
          Child A2
      Parent B
          Child B1
             Child B1a
             Child B1b
             Child B1c
```

In the above example - when I search for anyone tagged Parent A, I get every contact tagged Parent A and I get every contact tagged with any of the Children of Parent A.  This is what we want, so its great.  However, if I do a search for Child A1, I only get results for Child A1 and not the tags that Child A1 is the parent of.

Is this the correct behavior?  Can we change it?

Comment: IMO this is NOT correct behavior.

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech Is the correct behavior that Parent and Child Tags have no affiliation with each other, other than display? Or is the correct behavior that contacts with Child tags should appear when searching the Parent tag. Or is it non of the above?!

Comment: I would expect the latter - but either way is more internally consistent than the current behavior.  If parent/child tags had no affiliation with each other I'd be disappointed but assume there was a good reason.

Comment: Are your tags named in such a way that it might actually be picking up string comparison instead of parent-child? A quick glance at the code suggests it's using LIKE, so it will match any tag that contains the search term, which might be mistaken for parent-child if they are named similarly. In other words, I'm not sure it's actually doing any parent-child querying. A quick test on the public demo suggests it doesn't normally return results for child tags. What version are you using and how are you searching?

Comment: Super disappointing - I saw that in the demo - Ill have to retest again - maybe in future there will be a change. So the word now is Parent and Child Tags have no affiliation with each other, other than how tags are displayed.

Comment: @Demerit I think your comment should be the accepted answer.

Comment: I didn't post as answer because it wasn't a full look through the code or thorough testing and it really just prompted me to ask for more info about the config. And I didn't fully check what it actually is doing. But I appreciate the comment. My real problem right now is my Leafs can't seem to deal with Boston's top line.

Comment: I only have 11 minutes to award bounty! @JonG-MegaphoneTech @demerit!

Comment: or as soon as possible - free reputation to whoever answers.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why would a tag search of a child tag to also pick up everyone tagged in a parent? That would make being able to search by the child tag useless.

Comment: @Christia Thats not what is being questioned. The desired outcome is when parent tags are searched for - all contacts with children tags will also be included in results.

Comment: But your confusion may stem from the fact that children can be parents of other children. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The tags hierarchy are only used as a way to visually cluster them, but they are separate, and if you search on a parent tag, you won't get the contacts that are tagged with a child tag. Perhaps unexpected for you, but some organisations are using it with the parent tag being a kind of "unspecified/other", for instance having a parent tag "media" and children tags "TV", "blog", "newspaper": if one contact is tagged "media", it means "other media", ie. not TV, blog or newspaper.

This is different than the groups, where if you search on a parent group, it will include all the contacts that belong to one of its child group

As of why you got got the contacts tagged with a child tag of parent A... it might be the behaviour you want, but IMO it's a bug and shouldn't behave that way.